# Installing XAMPP on windows

Tags: php, apache, apache2, xampp, wamp

I was trying to install XAMPP on my windows machine and while it is installing it says installing Apache server failed because port 80 and 443 are already in use.

Since Skype is also using this port, i have uninstalled Skype and started re-installing XAMPP server.

But still after uninstalling Skype i get the same error message when XAMPP server is installing. Could someone has faced this issue before share your ideas with me

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You say port is already in use. Are you check it using other software (maybe) for know what other application runing using the port?

Answer (score 2):

At a command prompt type

```
netstat -a -n -o
```

to see which process is using the ports.

It's probably IIS if you've got that installed.

One way to fix it is to specify non-standard ports for XAMPP to use, such as 8080 and 8443.

Answer (score 0):

Have You IIS Service running? 
just check that IIS Service, when it running just stop it, you can stop it from Computer managment > Services